# How can I ensure that all wordpress and woocommerce functions get included in a piece of custom code?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to run a custompiece of code but I just have this in it's own PHP file.
How am I supposed to make sure that it 'inherits' all the functions of wordpress and woocommerce  so that it knows what to do?

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->update_status( 'completed' );
```

Comment: Is your custom code a plugin or a theme template?

Comment: Write a plugin and initialize it on the `woocommerce_loaded` hook.

Comment: Run your code inside WordPress instead of in a stand-alone file.